# Rewriting URL that contains question mark

Tags: php, url-rewriting, get, query-string

I am encountering a problem regarding URL rewriting. I am using Apache's mod rewrite to rewrite URLs. For example, I rewrite URL

- `www.website.com/some/path/` to
- `request.php?string=some/path/`.

Then I show specific response for this URL. Right now my rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_/\?]+)$ request.php?string=$1
```

But the problem begins if I have URL `www.website.com/some/data/?id=12&name=John` and rewrite it, I get something like this: `request.php?string=some/data/?id=12&name=John`. It seems that in this example another question mark confuses PHP. If I try to retrieve `$_GET['string']` in request.php all I get is: `some/data/`.

For further reference, Gmail does something similar with it's URL:
`https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=1&shva=1`

Comment: Have you tried the [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) flag yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest (as mario) to take a look into the [QSA flag (Query String Append)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). Additionally I would take the question-mark out of the character class in the regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_/]+)$ request.php?string=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and mario for great answer. It works even better than I expected, since I tough I'll have to parse get query myself.

Comment: @knustrle: No you don't have to, apache does that for you. It's documented in the rewrite docs as well. If you want to check for query-info-parts, you need to use RewriteCond. RewriteRule is about the path only.