# After URL re-write, what happen to the GET request

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rewriting URL that contains question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095704/rewriting-url-that-contains-question-mark)

Hi a noob question for url re-write

eg.

```
Http://localhost/example/index.php?url=test/test&id=123
```

after a URL rewrite the URL become

```
Http://localhost/example/test/test
```

Just wondering if the server side page still will get that `$_GET['id']` value and `$_GET['url']` value?

Thanks

Comment: Just a though i don't have a rule yet. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the GET params if you rewrited with [[QSA] flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to preserve existing query parameters, in other way, no. Because the regex on the RewriteRule is not run against the query parameters.